# Java : Word Diff in sentences using Google-diff-match-patch

Tags: java, google-diff-match-patch

Am using google-diff-match-patch for comparing 2 strings for Difference. It works fine for most part, except if the first Character in a word is the same.

For Ex:

```
Text1 = CHICAGO IL
Text2 = COLUMBUS OH
```

Output:

```
deltas: [Diff(EQUAL,"C"), Diff(DELETE,"HICAGO IL"), Diff(INSERT,"OLUMBUS OH")]
<span>C</span><span class='SS_ChangeDelete'>HICAGO IL</span><span class='SS_ChangeAdd'>OLUMBUS OH</span>
```

Desired Output:

```
deltas: [Diff(DELETE,"CHICAGO IL"), Diff(INSERT,"COLUMBUS OH")]
<span class='SS_ChangeDelete'>CHICAGO IL</span><span class='SS_ChangeAdd'>COLUMBUS OH</span>
```

Any Suggestions or if there is any other library out there can do the trick ? Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is your program supposed to do?

Comment: Its Supposed to find Word Difference between 2 sentences and return a merged sentence.For Ex:

Text1 = CHICAGO IL
Text2 = COLUMBUS OH

Expected = Striked(CHICAGO IL) Highlighted(COLUMBUS OH)

But am getting : NoChange(C) Striked(HICAGO IL) Highlighted(OLUMBUS OH)

Comment: @Ben I am facing same issue, were you able to get a solution? If yes, then can you please share.

Comment: @NeelamSharma I still have not got the solution. But the google wiki has some steps to resolve the word diff. Tried it, but did not work for me. https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-diff-match-patch/wikis/LineOrWordDiffs.wiki